# Automating following action in Instagram using Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, instagram

I am writing a bot to automate the following action in Instagram. The following code does work for fist 5X followers but after that, even Selenium does click the follow button, the status of the button does not change at all. Could anyone spot out any mistakes in my code?

```
# Import requiements
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

# Create our class
class InstagramBot:
    def __init__(self, username, password):
        self.username = '<my user name>'
        self.password = '<my password>'
        self.bot = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path = '<Driver Path>') 

    # Function will log us in to Instagram
    def login(self):
        bot = self.bot
        # Navigate to the Instagram login page
        bot.get('https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/')
        time.sleep(3)

        # Find the email and password boxes, enter login credentials
        email = bot.find_element_by_name('username').send_keys(self.username)
        password = bot.find_element_by_name('password').send_keys(self.password)

        # Wait for 1 second then press ENTER
        time.sleep(1)
        bot.find_element_by_name('password').send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

        # Wait 3 second while the post-login page loads
        time.sleep(3)


    def followTheirFollowers(self, number_to_follow):
        bot = self.bot
        
        bot.get('https://instagram.com/' + '<Target Account Name>')
        time.sleep(5)
        
        bot.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@href="/' + '<Target Account Name>' + '/follower/"]').click()
        time.sleep(2)
        
        j = 1
        
        while j <= number_to_follow:
            follow = bot.find_elements_by_xpath("//button[(text() = 'Follow')]")
            time.sleep(2)

            i = 1

            for follower in follow:
                if(i != 1):
                    bot.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", follower)
                    time.sleep(2)

                if(i > number_to_follow):
                    break

                i+=1
            
            j += 1
            popup = bot.find_element_by_class_name('isgrP')
            bot.execute_script('arguments[0].scrollTop = arguments[0].scrollHeight', popup)
            time.sleep(2)



insta = InstagramBot('USERNAME', 'PASSWORD')
insta.login()
insta.followTheirFollowers(5)
```

Comment: Did you try pressing that button manually to see if you can change the status when you find that the script failed to change the status?

Comment: yes, I did try to do it on the browser opened by running the script and it fails too. However, when I separately open another one, it works.

Comment: I think Instagram sort of banning or detecting automotive behavior; I also want to find a way to bypass this ban.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue here is very simple. The code itself looks fine.

Right at the bottom you're running the function `insta.followTheirFollowers(5)`, the argument in `followTheirFollowers()` is `number_to_follow`, meaning you're only telling the bot to do this five times. If you change this number, the bot should do it more than five times.

Comment: I did try to make it as 2000 but it still failed.

Comment: Do you receive an error after five follows?

Answer (score 0):

If your code is working for the first few cases and then stops working (the changes are not reflected upon refreshing the page), it is most probably the Instagram bot detection algorithms at play. You can randomize the sleep time such as `time.sleep(3 + random.random())` to mimic human clicking behaviour. You should be able to go a few extra cases with this.